# How to take some characters in a big text in excel

Tags: excel

I have in my excel one column that describe one apartment to sell, I want just one information in that column : the number of meters square. I want to know that exist one formula that take x characters inside that description. for example: *"Apartmento to sell, 45 m², 2 rooms,  4 bathrooms....."* I want the 45 number without I having to look every single line.

Comment: is the format all the same?  by that I mean, some description, a comma, the dimensions, another comma, and more description.  Or is the room dimensions in different places throughout?

Comment: the only mutual characters is the dimension of the apartment.  Just change is the number of the dimension, of course.

Comment: It's not of course or he wouldn't have had to ask.

Comment: in Google spreadsheet you can use `= REGEXEXTRACT( A1, "[0-9]+" )`, but in Excel you will most likely need a VBA UDF for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the position of m²
   =FIND("m²",A1,1)
2. Take the left of the text (cell) and your number should be at the end
   =LEFT(A1,FIND("m²",A1,1)-1)
3. If it always start with *Apartmento to sell, 45 m², 2 rooms, 4 bathrooms*
   =TRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(A1,FIND("m²",A1,1)-1),1,19,""))

Answer (score 0):

If the format is similar for all rows, then do `Text to Columns` (under the Data tab) and specify the delimiter as a Comma. Then, your second column will only have apartment dimensions

This works regardless of anything else, so long as there are at least two commas in each entry, and the dimensions are always between the first two commas.